# Laravel 7 adding the @ symbol before the username

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm workong on simple project with Laravel 7 and i want to activate a simple trick in my project
I want to add the @ symbol before the username like this example : **http://app.test/@jhondoe**

Live example : [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/@splendidkeen)

**this is my User profile Route :**

```
Route::get('profile/{slug}/{id}', 'Backend\UserController@UserProfile')->name('profile');
```

**This is User profile Controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   /**
     * Show the User Profile.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function UserProfile($slug, $id)
    {
        return view('profile');
    }
}
```

**This is a simple button to get access to User Profile :**

```
<a href="{{ URL('profile') }}/{{ Auth::user()->slug }}/{{ Auth::user()->id }}" class="btn btn-info">My Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new route

```
Route::get('@{user:slug}', 'Backend\UserController@UserProfile')->name('profile');
```

now receive the user in the controller

```
    public function UserProfile(User $user)
    {
        return view('profile',compact($user));
    }
```

then show the user's profile in the view, accessing `$user->` properties

This assumes you have a slug column on the User model and that this has been verified as unique when it was created

Comment: and what about the link to get access to the profile ?

Comment: change the route :`<a href="{{ route('profile', Auth::user() ) }}"`

Comment: I changed it but it show me this error Missing required parameters for [Route: profile] [URI: profile/@{user}/{id}]

Comment: because you did not change the route in web.php